# Mapping a dictionary values to a column using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values like below:

```
d = {'3': 'w_molly', '11': 'w_snug', '13':'w_dupe'}
```

The actual dictionary has around 120 values and generated from a .csv file.

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
KEY  TIME  VALUE
  3  20:00   6.9
  3  21:00   8.9
  3  23:00   4.9
 11  21:00   4.9
 11  23:00   9.9
 13  20:00  12.5
```

The data frame has millions of rows, what I want to do is replace the KEY column withe the dictionary values.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
KEY  TIME  VALUE
w_molly  20:00   6.9
w_molly  21:00   8.9
w_molly  23:00   4.9
w_snug   21:00   4.9
w_snug   23:00   9.9
w_dupe   20:00  12.5
```

I have tried the following:

```
df=df.replace({'KEY':d})
```

But I get Typeerror: cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and str

Can someone please help?

Comment: Use `df['KEY']=df['KEY'].map(d).fillna(df['KEY'])`

Comment: @jezrael Hi, thanks for the quick reply, when I try this the `df['KEY']` still displays the number instead of the 'w_' values...

Comment: Try: `df['KEY']=df['KEY'].astype(str).map(d).fillna(df['KEY'])`

Comment: @Erfan that did it, thanks!! This was wrecking my head all morning.